# Cumulative sums, moving averages, and SQL "group by" equivalents in R

Tags: r, average, time-series, moving-average

What's the most efficient way to create a moving average or rolling sum in R? How do you do the rolling function along with a "group by"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While zoo is great, sometimes there are simpler ways. If you data behaves nicely, and is evenly spaced, the embed() function effectively lets you create multiple lagged version of a time series. If you look inside the VARS package for vector auto-regression, you will see that the package author chooses this route.

For example, to calculate the 3 period rolling average of x, where x = (1 -> 20)^2:

```
> x <- (1:20)^2
> embed (x, 3)
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    9    4    1
 [2,]   16    9    4
 [3,]   25   16    9
 [4,]   36   25   16
 [5,]   49   36   25
 [6,]   64   49   36
 [7,]   81   64   49
 [8,]  100   81   64
 [9,]  121  100   81
[10,]  144  121  100
[11,]  169  144  121
[12,]  196  169  144
[13,]  225  196  169
[14,]  256  225  196
[15,]  289  256  225
[16,]  324  289  256
[17,]  361  324  289
[18,]  400  361  324
> apply (embed (x, 3), 1, mean)
 [1]   4.666667   9.666667  16.666667  25.666667  36.666667  49.666667
 [7]  64.666667  81.666667 100.666667 121.666667 144.666667 169.666667
[13] 196.666667 225.666667 256.666667 289.666667 324.666667 361.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

I scratched up a good answer from Achim Zeileis over on the r list. Here's what he said:

```
library(zoo)
## create data

x <- rnorm(365)
## transform to regular zoo series with "Date" index

x <- zooreg(x, start = as.Date("2004-01-01")) plot(x)

## add rolling/running/moving average with window size 7 

lines(rollmean(x, 7), col = 2, lwd = 2)

## if you don't want the rolling mean but rather a weekly ## time series of means you can do
nextfri <- function(x) 7 * ceiling(as.numeric(x - 1)/7) + as.Date(1) xw <- aggregate(x, nextfri, mean)

## nextfri is a function which computes for a certain "Date" ## the next friday. xw is then the weekly series. 

lines(xw, col = 4)
```

Achim went on to say:

> Note, that the difference between is
> rolling mean and the aggregated series
> is due to different alignments. This
> can be changed by changing the 'align'
> argument in `rollmean()` or the
> `nextfri()` function in the aggregate
> call.

All this came from Achim, not from me:
http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/06/6785.html