# Lagging Variables in R

Tags: r, time-series

What is the most efficient way to make a matrix of lagged variables in R for an arbitrary variable (i.e. not a regular time series)

For example:

***Input***:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

***2 lags, output***:

```
[1,NA, NA]
[2, 1, NA]
[3, 2,  1]
[4, 3,  2]
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can achieve this using the built-in `embed()` function, where its second 'dimension' argument is equivalent to what you've called 'lag':

```
x <- c(NA,NA,1,2,3,4)
embed(x,3)

## returns
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   NA   NA
[2,]    2    1   NA
[3,]    3    2    1
[4,]    4    3    2
```

`embed()` was discussed in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169376/cumulative-sums-moving-averages-and-sql-group-by-equivalents-in-r/1172367#1172367) by Joshua Reich.  (Note that I prepended x with NAs to replicate your desired output).

It's not particularly well-named but it is quite useful and powerful for operations involving sliding windows, such as rolling sums and moving averages.

Comment: More generally:
lagmatrix <- function(x,max.lag){embed(c(rep(NA,max.lag),x),max.lag+1)}
Then use lagmatrix(1:4,2)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the embed function.  This saved a massive amount of computing time for me.

Answer (score 9):

Use a proper `class` for your objects; base R has `ts` which has a `lag()` function to operate on.  Note that these `ts` objects came from a time when 'delta' or 'frequency' where constant:  monthly or quarterly data as in macroeconomic series.

For irregular data such as (business-)daily, use the [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) or [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts) packages which can also deal (very well!) with lags.  To go further from there, you can use packages like [dynlm](http://cran.r-project.org/package=dynlm) or [dlm](http://cran.r-project.org/package=dlm) allow for dynamic regression models with lags.

The Task Views on Time Series, Econometrics, Finance all have further pointers.

Answer (score 2):

The `running` function in the `gtools` package does more or less what you want:

```
> require("gtools")
> running(1:4, fun=I, width=3, allow.fewer=TRUE)

$`1:1`
[1] 1

$`1:2` 
[1] 1 2

$`1:3` 
[1] 1 2 3

$`2:4` 
[1] 2 3 4
```

Comment: But James wanted a matrix not a list. You could package the result using matrix(unlist(...)) but the embed() function does it in one step.

Comment: Totally right, which is why I upvoted the embed() solution when it came out =).  But 'running' is still a useful function I think --- most of the time when I wanted to create the matrix James asked for, what I really wanted to do was run apply on it.

Answer (score 1):

The method that works best for me
is to use the `lag` function from the `dplyr` package.

Example:

```
> require(dplyr)
> lag(1:10, 1)
 [1] NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
> lag(1:10, 2)
 [1] NA NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```