# Basic lag in R vector/dataframe

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

Will most likely expose that I am new to R, but in SPSS, running lags is very easy.  Obviously this is user error, but what I am missing?

```
x <- sample(c(1:9), 10, replace = T)
y <- lag(x, 1)
ds <- cbind(x, y)
ds
```

Results in:

```
      x y
 [1,] 4 4
 [2,] 6 6
 [3,] 3 3
 [4,] 4 4
 [5,] 3 3
 [6,] 5 5
 [7,] 8 8
 [8,] 9 9
 [9,] 3 3
[10,] 7 7
```

I figured I would see:

```
     x y
 [1,] 4 
 [2,] 6 4
 [3,] 3 6
 [4,] 4 3
 [5,] 3 4
 [6,] 5 3
 [7,] 8 5
 [8,] 9 8
 [9,] 3 9
[10,] 7 3
```

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Another way to deal with this is using the zoo package, which has a lag method that will pad the result with NA:

```
require(zoo)
> set.seed(123)
> x <- zoo(sample(c(1:9), 10, replace = T))
> y <- lag(x, -1, na.pad = TRUE)
> cbind(x, y)
   x  y
1  3 NA
2  8  3
3  4  8
4  8  4
5  9  8
6  1  9
7  5  1
8  9  5
9  5  9
10 5  5
```

The result is a multivariate zoo object (which is an enhanced matrix), but easily converted to a data.frame via

```
> data.frame(cbind(x, y))
```

Comment: Also note that if z is a zoo series then lag(z, 0:-1) is a two column zoo series with the original series and a lagged series.  Also, coredata(z) will return just the data part of a zoo series and as.data.frame(z) will return a data frame with the data part of z as the column contents.

Comment: Am I the only one finding that zoo is getting k backwards? In this example k=-1 is negative so I would expect y to be leading, but it's in fact lagging behind x.
The default is k=1 so if I write "y = lag(x)", I end up with y leading x. This is... misleading.

Comment: zoo's design principles include consistency with base R and in base R a positive lag causes the series to start earlier.  See ?lag

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, just came to this post with a similar problem and tried running your accepted solution, but got this error: `Error: "n" must be a nonnegative integer scalar, not an integer vector of length 1.`  Changing the `-1` to `1` eliminates the error, but raises the question as to whether something has changed since you wrote this solution -- of which readers of this post should be aware.  Care to comment?  Thanks.

Comment: @W Barker, You likely introduced an error by loading dplyr which clobbers `lag` in the base of R.  Use `library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))` or don't load dplyr.

Answer (score 36):

I had the same problem, but I didn't want to use zoo or xts, so I wrote a simple [lag function for data frames](https://heuristically.wordpress.com/2012/10/29/lag-function-for-data-frames/):

```
lagpad <- function(x, k) {
  if (k>0) {
    return (c(rep(NA, k), x)[1 : length(x)] );
  }
  else {
    return (c(x[(-k+1) : length(x)], rep(NA, -k)));
  }
}
```

This can lag forward or backwards:

```
x<-1:3;
(cbind(x, lagpad(x, 1), lagpad(x,-1)))
     x      
[1,] 1 NA  2
[2,] 2  1  3
[3,] 3  2 NA
```

Comment: Lets say I wanted to do this function on a vector but preform it recursively for multiple lags `lagpad(x,-1:-216)` and output that information into one dataframe (e.g. lagpad(x,-1) becomes variable #1 of the df, lagpad(x,-2) becomes variable #2 of the df,lagpad(x,-3) becomes variable #3 of the df...and so on. would I have to cbind 216 columns or is there a shorter way to adapt your code to this scenario?

Answer (score 15):

`lag` does not shift the data, it only shifts the "time-base".  `x` has no "time base", so `cbind` does not work as you expected.  Try `cbind(as.ts(x),lag(x))` and notice that a "lag" of 1 shifts the periods *forward*.

I would suggesting using `zoo` / `xts` for time series.  The `zoo` vignettes are particularly helpful.

Comment: Neither `zoo` nor `xts` seems to be stock, where do I get them?

Comment: `install.packages("xts")  # this will install zoo as well`

Answer (score 10):

Using just standard R functions this can be achieved in a much simpler way:

```
x <- sample(c(1:9), 10, replace = T)
y <- c(NA, head(x, -1))
ds <- cbind(x, y)
ds
```

Answer (score 7):

`lag()` works with time series, whereas you are trying to use bare matrices.  [This old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311920/lagging-variables-in-r) suggests using `embed` instead, like so:

```
lagmatrix <- function(x,max.lag) embed(c(rep(NA,max.lag), x), max.lag+1)
```

for instance

```
> x
[1] 8 2 3 9 8 5 6 8 5 8
> lagmatrix(x, 1)
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    8   NA
 [2,]    2    8
 [3,]    3    2
 [4,]    9    3
 [5,]    8    9
 [6,]    5    8
 [7,]    6    5
 [8,]    8    6
 [9,]    5    8
[10,]    8    5
```

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to me now appears to be the following:

```
require(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(c(1:9), 10, replace = T))
df <- df %>% mutate(y = lag(x))
```

Comment: Yes! In any context it seems, just swap dplyr::lag for standard lag and then works fine on non time series... job done!

Answer (score 2):

```
tmp<-rnorm(10)
tmp2<-c(NA,tmp[1:length(tmp)-1])
tmp
tmp2
```

Answer (score 2):

This should accommodate vectors or matrices as well as negative lags:

```
lagpad <- function(x, k=1) {
  i<-is.vector(x)
  if(is.vector(x)) x<-matrix(x) else x<-matrix(x,nrow(x))
  if(k>0) {
      x <- rbind(matrix(rep(NA, k*ncol(x)),ncol=ncol(x)), matrix(x[1:(nrow(x)-k),], ncol=ncol(x)))
  }
  else {
      x <- rbind(matrix(x[(-k+1):(nrow(x)),], ncol=ncol(x)),matrix(rep(NA, -k*ncol(x)),ncol=ncol(x)))
  }
  if(i) x[1:length(x)] else x
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
> x <- sample(c(1:9), 10, replace = T)
> y <- data.table::shift(x)
> ds <- cbind(x, y)
> ds
      x  y
 [1,] 5 NA
 [2,] 4  5
 [3,] 3  4
 [4,] 3  3
 [5,] 4  3
 [6,] 8  4
 [7,] 1  8
 [8,] 7  1
 [9,] 9  7
[10,] 7  9
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to do the same may be copying the data to a new data
frame and changing the index number. Make sure the original table is indexed sequentially with no gaps

e.g.

```
tempData <- originalData
rownames(tempData) <- 2:(nrow(tempData)+1)
```

if you want it in the same data frame as the original use a cbind function

Answer (score 0):

Two options, in `base R` and with `data.table`:

```
baseShiftBy1 <- function(x) c(NA, x[-length(x)])
baseShiftBy1(x)
[1] NA  3  8  4  8  9  1  5  9  5

data.table::shift(x)
[1] NA  3  8  4  8  9  1  5  9  5
```

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
(x <- sample(c(1:9), 10, replace = T))
[1] 3 8 4 8 9 1 5 9 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with a similar solution to [Andrew's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13128713/5213451) (dedicated function instead of `xts` or `zoo`), but with a terser formulation that I find easier to reason about:

```r
lagpad <- function(x, k) {
  if (k == 0) { return(x) }
  k.pos <- max(0, k)
  k.neg <- max(0, -k)
  c(rep(NA, k.pos), head(x, -k.pos),  # empty if k<0, else lagging x
    tail(x, -k.neg), rep(NA, k.neg))  # empty if k>0, else leading x
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just get rid of lag. Change your line for y to:

```
y <- c(NA, x[-1])
```

Comment: this is not correct! Probably you wanted to say `y <- c(NA, head(x, -1))`