# Lagging/Differencing Variables in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basic lag in R vector/dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558988/basic-lag-in-r-vector-dataframe)

Trying to lag a variable in R but it isn't working.

```
x<-1:10
y=lag(x,1)
xy=cbind(x,y)
View(xy)

    x   y
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
4   4   4
5   5   5
6   6   6
7   7   7
8   8   8
9   9   9
10  10  10
```

I am still not getting the lag. What am I doing wrong? Also is there a quicker way to combine to vectors/matrices without using cbind/rbind? For example

```
x=0:10
y=20:30
newxy=[x,y]
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can find answer in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558988/basic-lag-in-r-vector-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lag()` expects a time series.  (In R, class "ts" is the basic time-series class, used to represent data sampled at equispaced points in time.  For more see `?ts`.)  So you can either convert x to a time-series, as demonstrated here, or make use one of the approaches suggested in another answer.

```
x <- as.ts(1:10)
y <- lag(x,1)
xy <- cbind(x,y)
xy
#Time Series:
#Start = 0 
#End = 10 
#Frequency = 1 
#    x  y
# 0 NA  1
# 1  1  2
# 2  2  3
# 3  3  4
# 4  4  5
# 5  5  6
# 6  6  7
# 7  7  8
# 8  8  9
# 9  9 10
#10 10 NA
```

Answer (score 2):

For the second part:

```
newxy=matrix(c(x,y),ncol=2)

> newxy
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    0   20
 [2,]    1   21
 [3,]    2   22
 [4,]    3   23
 [5,]    4   24
 [6,]    5   25
 [7,]    6   26
 [8,]    7   27
 [9,]    8   28
[10,]    9   29
[11,]   10   30
```

Answer (score 2):

`embed` is a useful function here, especially if you don't want to convert to  a `ts` object.

```
x <- 1:10
embed(x,2)


     [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    2    1
 [2,]    3    2
 [3,]    4    3
 [4,]    5    4
 [5,]    6    5
 [6,]    7    6
 [7,]    8    7
 [8,]    9    8
 [9,]   10    9
```