# Remove/collapse consecutive duplicate values in sequence

Tags: r, loops, apply, lag

I have the following *dataframe*:

```
a a a b c c d e a a b b b e e d d
```

The required result should be

```
a b c d e a b e d
```

It means no two consecutive rows should have same value. How it can be done without using loop.

As my data set is quite huge, looping is taking lot of time to execute.

The dataframe structure is like the following

```
a 1 
a 2
a 3
b 2
c 4
c 1
d 3
e 9
a 4
a 8
b 10
b 199
e 2
e 5
d 4
d 10
```

Result:

```
a 1 
b 2
c 4
d 3
e 9
a 4
b 10
e 2
d 4
```

Its should delete the entire row.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One easy way is to use `rle`:

Here's your sample data:

```
x <- scan(what = character(), text = "a a a b c c d e a a b b b e e d d")
# Read 17 items
```

`rle` returns a `list` with two values: the run length ("`lengths`"), and the value that is repeated for that run ("`values`").

```
rle(x)$values
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "a" "b" "e" "d"
```

---

#### Update: For a `data.frame`

If you are working with a `data.frame`, try something like the following:

```
## Sample data
mydf <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", 
         "a", "a", "b", "b", "e", "e", "d", "d"),
  V2 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 9, 
         4, 8, 10, 199, 2, 5, 4, 10)
)

## Use rle, as before
X <- rle(mydf$V1)
## Identify the rows you want to keep
Y <- cumsum(c(1, X$lengths[-length(X$lengths)]))
Y
# [1]  1  4  5  7  8  9 11 13 15
mydf[Y, ]
#    V1 V2
# 1   a  1
# 4   b  2
# 5   c  4
# 7   d  3
# 8   e  9
# 9   a  4
# 11  b 10
# 13  e  2
# 15  d  4
```

---

#### Update 2

The "data.table" package has a function `rleid` that lets you do this quite easily. Using `mydf` from above, try:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, .SD[1], by = rleid(V1)]
#    rleid V2
# 1:     1  1
# 2:     2  2
# 3:     3  4
# 4:     4  3
# 5:     5  9
# 6:     6  4
# 7:     7 10
# 8:     8  2
# 9:     9  4
```

Comment: How can i use this in the data.frame?
If i would use this in list, then again i have to map this unique values with the old data.frame but then its not possible to map as the length is less. 
What my purpose is to remove the entire row of the dataframe whenever i would get the same value in consecutive rows for a particular column.

Comment: Nice answer!  For you first ``data.frame`` solution, I found I needed ``X <- rle(as.numeric(mydf$V1))``, as ``V1`` is a factor. Other remark: I found that in some cases ``cumsum(X$lengths)`` would do the job, depending on which duplicate rows you wish to keep (top to bottom v. bottom to top), do you confirm?

Answer (score 13):

```
library(dplyr)
x <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "e", "e", "d", "d")
x[x!=lag(x, default=1)]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "a" "b" "e" "d"
```

**EDIT**: For `data.frame`

```
  mydf <- data.frame(
    V1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", 
         "a", "a", "b", "b", "e", "e", "d", "d"),
    V2 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 9, 
         4, 8, 10, 199, 2, 5, 4, 10),
   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

dplyr solution is one liner:

```
mydf %>% filter(V1!= lag(V1, default="1"))
#  V1 V2
#1  a  1
#2  b  2
#3  c  4
#4  d  3
#5  e  9
#6  a  4
#7  b 10
#8  e  2
#9  d  4
```

**post scriptum**

`lead(x,1)` suggested by @Carl Witthoft iterates in reverse order.

```
leadit<-function(x) x!=lead(x, default="what")
rows <- leadit(mydf[ ,1])
mydf[rows, ]

#   V1  V2
#3   a   3
#4   b   2
#6   c   1
#7   d   3
#8   e   9
#10  a   8
#12  b 199
#14  e   5
#16  d  10
```

Comment: Could it be that you're using `dplyr::lag` here? I tried your code with a clean session and it doenst work with `stats::lag`

Answer (score 6):

With base R, I like funny algorithmics:

```
x <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "e", "e", "d", "d")

x[x!=c(x[-1], FALSE)]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "a" "b" "e" "d"
```

Comment: Similarly could use indexing instead of `tail`, something like `x[x != c(x[-1], FALSE)]`

Comment: I struggled to adapt this to factors inside a ``data.frame``. Within a dataframe, the rhs, ``FALSE`` constrains the vector to be of type ``integer``, so on the lhs ``x`` must be so constrained for the comparison to be possible, with ``as.integer()``. Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: sorry but it's very unclear ... you can ask a question on SO if you are meeting an issue on such a topic, with your input, output and what you have done so far.

Answer (score 3):

Much as I like,... errr, *love* `rle` , here's a shootoff:

EDIT: Can't figure out exactly what's up with `dplyr` so I used `dplyr::lead` . I'm on OSX, R3.1.2, and latest `dplyr` from CRAN.

```
xlet<-sample(letters,1e5,rep=T)
rleit<-function(x) rle(x)$values
lagit<-function(x) x[x!=lead(x, default=1)]
tailit<-function(x) x[x!=c(tail(x,-1), tail(x,1))]



  microbenchmark(rleit(xlet),lagit(xlet),tailit(xlet),times=20)
Unit: milliseconds
         expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
  rleit(xlet) 27.43996 30.02569 30.20385 30.92817 37.10657    20
  lagit(xlet) 12.44794 15.00687 15.14051 15.80254 46.66940    20
 tailit(xlet) 12.48968 14.66588 14.78383 15.32276 55.59840    20
```

Comment: Did `lagit` work for you? It returns nothing to me. Maybe this is why its the fastest....

Comment: I think you need to re run this after loading `dplyr`, as I suspect `lagit` isnt doing anything currently and thus very fast

Comment: Oops, yep-- I didn't check the outputs.  But what's up?  I see "lag" listed under "leadlag" but there's no actual function `dplyr::lag`

Comment: The `tailit` function in your benchmark is missing the last "d" in the vector.. perhaps update to `x[x!=c(x[-1], FALSE)]` as in the answer

Comment: Seems like `lead` is little slower than `lag`. Why is that so? https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/lead-lag.R

Comment: @DavidArenburg Upon reflection, `lagit` returned zero because I had a wide range of values so there weren't any repeats.  If you rerun my case with `xlet<-sample(letters[1:7],1e5,rep=T)` you'll get some hits.

Comment: Is there any **LAG** function equivalent in R ??

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636929/retain-and-lag-function-in-r-as-sas)

I have tried this but did n't work.

Answer (score 0):

Tidyverse solution:

```
x <- scan(what = character(), text = "a a a b c c d e a a b b b e e d d")
x <- tibble(x)
x |> 
 mutate(id = consecutive_id(x)) |> 
 distinct(x, id)
```

In addition, if there is another column `y` associated with the consecutive values column, this solution allows some flexibility:

```
x <- scan(what = character(), text = "a a a b c c d e a a b b b e e d d")
x <- tibble(x, y = runif(length(x)))
x |> 
    group_by(id = consecutive_id(x)) |> 
    slice_min(y)
```

We can choose between the different slice functions, like slice_max, slice_min, slice_head, and slice_tail.

This Stack Overflow thread appeared in the second edition of R4DS, in the Numbers chapter of the book.