# R: Remove consecutive duplicates from comma separated string

Tags: r, csv, duplicates

I'm having issues removing just the right amount of information from the following data:

> 18,14,17,2,9,8
>   17,17,17,14
>   18,14,17,2,1,1,1,1,9,8,1,1,1

I'm applying !duplicate in order to remove the duplicates.

```
SplitFunction <- function(x) {
  b <- unlist(strsplit(x, '[,]'))
  c <- b[!duplicated(b)]
  return(paste(c, collapse=","))
}
```

I'm having issues removing only consecutive duplicates. The result below is what I'm getting.

> 18,14,17,2,9,8
>   17,14
>   18,14,17,2,1,9,8

The data below is what I want to obtain.

> 18,14,17,2,9,8
>   17,14
>   18,14,17,2,1,9,8,1

Can you suggest a way to perform this? Ideally a vectorized approach...
Thanks,
Miguel

Comment: please provide a reproducible sample of your data (using `dput()`)

Comment: c("18,14,17,2,9,8", "17,17,17,14", "14,17,18,2,9,8,1", "18,14,17,11,8,9,8,8,22,13,6", 
"14,17,2,9,8", "18,14,17,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,9,8,1,1,1,1")  This is the head of the data. It is a column in a data.table, but it can be changed to other format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use rle function to sovle this question.

```
xx <- c("18,14,17,2,9,8","17,17,17,14","18,14,17,2,1,1,1,1,9,8,1,1,1")
zz <- strsplit(xx,",")
sapply(zz,function(x) rle(x)$value)
```

And you can refer to this link.
[How to remove/collapse consecutive duplicate values in sequence in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482712/how-to-remove-collapse-consecutive-duplicate-values-in-sequence-in-r)

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rle`

```
sapply(strsplit(x, ','), function(x) paste(inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x), 
            lengths <- rep(1, length(lengths)))), collapse=","))
#[1] "18,14,17,2,9,8"     "17,14"              "18,14,17,2,1,9,8,1"
```

#### data

```
x <- c('18,14,17,2,9,8', '17,17,17,14', '18,14,17,2,1,1,1,1,9,8,1,1,1')
```

Comment: Instead of `inverse.rle`, you could just extract the "values" element -- `sapply(strsplit(x, ','), function(X) paste(rle(X)$values, collapse = ","))`

Answer (score 2):

Great rle-answers. This is just to add an alternative without rle. This gives a list of numeric vectors but can of course easily expanded to return strings:

```
numbers <- c("18,14,17,2,9,8", "17,17,17,14", "14,17,18,2,9,8,1", "18,14,17,11,8,9,8,8,22,13,6", "14,17,2,9,8", "18,14,17,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,9,8,1,1,1,1") 
result <- sapply(strsplit(numbers, ","), function(x) x[x!=c(x[-1],Inf)])
print(result)
```