# eliminating continuous values

Tags: r

```
Des          Price                                New column 

a   27.82 / 27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82                   27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82

b   19.87 / 19.87 / 19.14 / 19.87                   19.87 / 19.14 / 19.87

c   32.25 / 32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31                 32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31

d   79.39 / 79.39 / 79.39 / 79.39 / 83.36 / 79.39   79.39 / 83.36 / 79.39
```

I have a price column . I need new column only eliminating continuous repititve values. PLease suggest. I first row, since 27.82 is continuously repitive, it should be made as 1 and the out put should be 27.82/23.65/27.82

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add example of your data using `dput` function (`dput(head(DATA))`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove/collapse consecutive duplicate values in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482712/remove-collapse-consecutive-duplicate-values-in-sequence)

Comment: I my case it is seperated by '/'. I am not getting

Answer (score 0):

```
test=c("27.82 / 27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82","19.87 / 19.87 / 19.14 / 19.87","32.25 / 32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31","79.39 / 79.39 / 79.39 / 79.39 / 83.36 / 79.39")
unlist(lapply(strsplit(test," / "),function(x) paste(rle(x)$values,collapse=" / ")))
```

Basically I built your Price vector in `test`. What's going on here is:

1. I divide each row of your 1-column vector into its parts with strsplit.
2. To each of those elements, I check for the repeated contiguous elements (like Unix `uniq`) using `rle`, which generates a list with a element called `values` in which the uniqed values are stored.
3. I `paste` all these values with `paste`, collapse option is used to set the separator to the same that was being used before.
4. As this has generated a list, I `unlist` it to generate a column.

Output:

```
> unlist(lapply(strsplit(test," / "),function(x) paste(rle(x)$values,collapse=" / ")))
[1] "27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82"   "19.87 / 19.14 / 19.87"   "32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31" "79.39 / 83.36 / 79.39"
```

By the way, next time it would be better if you provided the community with a reproducible example (so readers don't have to write your data into a object by themselves), plus show what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach, using `tidyverse`:

Data

```
vect <- c('27.82 / 27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82',
          '19.87 / 19.87 / 19.14 / 19.87',
          '32.25 / 32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31',
          '79.39 / 79.39 / 79.39 / 79.39 / 83.36 / 79.39')
```

Code

```
library(tidyverse)
vect %>% 
  str_split( ' / ') %>% 
  map(~.x[.x!=lag(.x) | is.na(lag(.x))]) %>% 
  map_chr(paste, collapse=' / ')
```

Output

```
[1] "27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82"   "19.87 / 19.14 / 19.87"   
[3] "32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31" "79.39 / 83.36 / 79.39"
```

Answer (score 0):

Data:
data<-data.frame(Des=c("a","b","c","d"),price=c('27.82 / 27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82', '19.87 / 19.87 / 19.14 / 19.87','32.25 / 32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 32.25','79.39 / 79.39 / 79.39 / 79.39 / 83.36 / 79.39'))

```
  Des                                         price
1   a                 27.82 / 27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82
2   b                 19.87 / 19.87 / 19.14 / 19.87
3   c            32.25 / 32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31
4   d 79.39 / 79.39 / 79.39 / 79.39 / 83.36 / 79.39
```

Code:

```
data$`New Column`<-gsub("\\b([\\w\\.]+)( / \\1\\b)+","\\1",data$price,perl = T)
```

Outcome:

```
Des                                         price            New Column
1   a                 27.82 / 27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82   27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82
2   b                 19.87 / 19.87 / 19.14 / 19.87   19.87 / 19.14 / 19.87
3   c               32.25 / 32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31   32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31
4   d 79.39 / 79.39 / 79.39 / 79.39 / 83.36 / 79.39   79.39 / 83.36 / 79.39
```

Comment: Got it. However can we a new dimension to the data. For example, In new column we have 27.82 / 23.65 / 27.82, so can we add another column and tell, the price decreased and increased. I mean the initial value was 27.82, then it got decreased and then increased. Similarly for 32.25 / 31 / 32.25 / 31, here it is decreased, increased, decreased.

Comment: Hi I got the out put the problem is for 5 / 6 /16 / 5 it is taking as 5/16/2005 and for 2/1/1/1 it is taking as 43132. please suggest

Comment: because you skip the spaces

Comment: No in R the output is fine. But when i export to excel . it is converting as date

Comment: Can we change the special character to > instead of /. Then I think we don't get it. What I say