# What's the opposite function to lag for an R vector/dataframe?

Tags: r, time-series, lag, lead

I have a problem dealing with time series in R.

```
#--------------read data

wb = loadWorkbook("Countries_Europe_Prices.xlsx") 
df = readWorksheet(wb, sheet="Sheet2")

x <- df$Year
y <- df$Index1

y <- lag(y, 1, na.pad = TRUE)
cbind(x, y)
```

It gives me the following output:

```
        x     y
 [1,] 1974    NA
 [2,] 1975  50.8
 [3,] 1976  51.9
 [4,] 1977  54.8
 [5,] 1978  58.8
 [6,] 1979  64.0
 [7,] 1980  68.8
 [8,] 1981  73.6
 [9,] 1982  74.3
[10,] 1983  74.5
[11,] 1984  72.9
[12,] 1985  72.1
[13,] 1986  72.3
[14,] 1987  71.7
[15,] 1988  72.9
[16,] 1989  75.3
[17,] 1990  81.2
[18,] 1991  84.3
[19,] 1992  87.2
[20,] 1993  90.1
```

But I want the first value in y to be 50.8 and so forth. In other words, I want to get a negative lag. I don't get it, how can I do it?

My problem is very similar to this problem, but however I cannot solve it. I guess I still do not understand the solution(s)...

[Basic lag in R vector/dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558988/basic-lag-in-r-vector-dataframe)

Comment: Can you dput your y vector?

Comment: Another option is of course `y <- c(y[-1], NA)`.

Comment: What is dput? 
@jbaums Wow, that really is an easy solution to my problem! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: For reference, `y[-1]` drops the first element of `y`, and `c` combines its arguments into a vector. Also, `dput` returns the structure of an object (e.g. `dput(df)`), and providing this in future will help us to reproduce your problems - see `?dput`.

Comment: Ok, perfect! Thanks a lot. How to proceed if I want the first element to be kept (not an NA value)? There probably would be a problem with the length of the vectors...?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can offset `x` instead, but either way you'll have an `NA` (or some other value you introduce) there somewhere.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about the built-in 'lead' function? (from the dplyr package)
Doesn't it do exactly the job of Ahmed's function?

```
cbind(x, lead(y, 1))
```

If you want to be able to calculate either positive or negative lags in the same function, i suggest a 'shorter' version of his 'shift' function:

```
shift = function(x, lag) {
  require(dplyr)
  switch(sign(lag)/2+1.5, lead(x, abs(lag)), lag(x, abs(lag)))
}
```

What it does is creating 2 cases, one with lag the other with lead, and chooses one case depending on the sign of your lag (the +1.5 is a trick to transform a {-1, +1} into a {1, 2} alternative).

Comment: I will try this solution later on. Didn't think about the dplyr package. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect solution! Really! Many thanks to all of you :)

Answer (score 3):

There is an easier way of doing this which I have captured fully from [this link](http://www.r-bloggers.com/generating-a-laglead-variables/). What I will do here is explaining what should you do in steps:

First create the following function by running the following code:

```
shift<-function(x,shift_by){
    stopifnot(is.numeric(shift_by))
    stopifnot(is.numeric(x))

    if (length(shift_by)>1)
        return(sapply(shift_by,shift, x=x))

    out<-NULL
    abs_shift_by=abs(shift_by)
    if (shift_by > 0 )
        out<-c(tail(x,-abs_shift_by),rep(NA,abs_shift_by))
    else if (shift_by < 0 )
        out<-c(rep(NA,abs_shift_by), head(x,-abs_shift_by))
    else
        out<-x
    out
}
```

This will create a function called `shift` with two arguments; one is the vector you need to operate its lag/lead and the other is number of lags/leads you need.

Example:

Suppose you have the following vector:

```
x<-seq(1:10)

x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

if you need `x`'s first order lag

```
shift(x,-1)
[1] NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

if you need `x`'s first order lead (negative lag)

```
shift(x,1)
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 NA
```

Comment: know about the 'lead' function?

Comment: @agenis Just checked that. It did the same like the function `shift` above (for the positive part only). The negative part should be done by the usual `lag` function.

Comment: How do I apply the shift function "by group"? In that I don't want the first record to refer to the previous group?

Answer (score 3):

Simpler solution:

```
y = dplyr::lead(y,1)
```

Answer (score 3):

The opposite of lag() function is lead()

Comment: If your answer is too short, you can send it like a comment.