# Speed up for loop with two if statements

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I have a data table `DT` with 15,000+ rows. I have a `for` loop that runs correctly, but it takes 30+ seconds and is the slowest part of the code overall. Here is the `for` loop:

```
for (i in 2:nrow(DT)) {
 if(DT$C1[i] == DT$C1[i+1] & DT$C2[i] != DT$C2[i+1] & DT$C3[i+1] - DT$C3[i] <= 4 & DT$C2[i] == "Short" & DT$C2[i+1] != "Long") DT$C4[i] = 1 else 
  if(DT$C1[i] == DT$C1[i-1] & DT$C2[i] != DT$C2[i-1] & DT$C3[i] - DT$C3[i-1] <= 4 & DT$C2[i] == "Short" & DT$C2[i-1] != "Long") DT$C4[i] = 1 else
      0 }
```

Is there any way to speed this up? I have seen some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908822/speed-up-the-loop-operation-in-r) and elsewhere, but they don't quite solve my particular issue with `i+1` and `i-1`.

Here is some example data.

```
C1 <- c("1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4")
C2 <- c("Short","Short","Short","None","None","Short","Short","Other","Long","Long","Long","Long","Long","Long","Long","Long","Short","Short","Other","Short","Short","None","Short","None","Other","Short","Short","Short","Short")
C3 <- c(as.Date("2010-06-01"),as.Date("2010-06-05"),as.Date("2010-06-09"),as.Date("2010-06-13"),as.Date("2010-06-17"),as.Date("2010-06-02"),as.Date("2010-06-21"),as.Date("2010-07-09"),as.Date("2010-07-13"),as.Date("2010-07-17"),as.Date("2010-07-21"),as.Date("2010-08-01"),as.Date("2010-08-05"),as.Date("2010-08-09"),as.Date("2010-09-03"),as.Date("2010-09-07"),as.Date("2010-06-03"),as.Date("2010-06-07"),as.Date("2010-06-11"),as.Date("2010-06-14"),as.Date("2010-06-17"),as.Date("2010-06-21"),as.Date("2010-06-24"),as.Date("2010-06-27"),as.Date("2010-07-01"),as.Date("2010-07-05"),as.Date("2010-07-09"),as.Date("2010-07-13"),as.Date("2010-07-17"))

DF <- data.frame(C1=C1, C2=C2, C3=C3)
DT <- as.data.table(DF)
```

And the desired output.

```
C1  C2      C3          C4
1   Short   2010-06-01  0
1   Short   2010-06-05  0
1   Short   2010-06-09  1
1   None    2010-06-13  0
1   None    2010-06-17  0
2   Short   2010-06-02  0
2   Short   2010-06-21  0
2   Other   2010-07-09  0
3   Long    2010-07-13  0
3   Long    2010-07-17  0
3   Long    2010-07-21  0
3   Long    2010-08-01  0
3   Long    2010-08-05  0
3   Long    2010-08-09  0
3   Long    2010-09-03  0
3   Long    2010-09-07  0
4   Short   2010-06-03  0
4   Short   2010-06-07  1
4   Other   2010-06-11  0
4   Short   2010-06-14  1
4   Short   2010-06-17  1
4   None    2010-06-21  0
4   Short   2010-06-24  1
4   None    2010-06-27  0
4   Other   2010-07-01  0
4   Short   2010-07-05  1
4   Short   2010-07-09  0
4   Short   2010-07-13  0
4   Short   2010-07-17  0
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please provide and example data set that this loop will give desired output.

Comment: I think you should probably just create a new column or index that represents the lag and lead of your columns in question, and then do away with the loop in favor of a vectorized logic operation. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558988/basic-lag-in-r-vector-dataframe) for examples on how to do a lag/lead with a `data.frame` object.

Comment: Did you add that second if statement to handle the beginning and end of your vectors? You may be able to replace one of them.

Comment: Added example data and desired output. Thanks for taking a look everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorize this with something like:

```
n <- nrow(DT)
DT$C4 <- NA  # Initialize however you want
# Warning -- untested due to no reproducible example...
DT$C4[2:(n-1)] <- as.numeric((DT$C1[2:(n-1)] == DT$C1[3:n] & DT$C2[2:(n-1)] != DT$C2[3:n] & DT$C3[3:n] - DT$C3[2:(n-1)] <= 4 & DT$C2[2:(n-1)] == "Short" & DT$C2[3:n] != "Long") |
                             (DT$C1[2:(n-1)] == DT$C1[1:(n-2)] & DT$C2[2:(n-1)] != DT$C2[1:(n-2)] & DT$C3[2:(n-1)] - DT$C3[1:(n-2)] <= 4 & DT$C2[2:(n-1)] == "Short" & DT$C2[1:(n-2)] != "Long"))
```

Basically each time you indexed by `i` in the loop you replace that with `2:(n-1)`, each time you indexed with `i-1` you replace that with `1:(n-2)`, and each time you indexed with `i+1` you replace that with `3:n`.

Comment: Thank you! This is so much faster. 0.02 seconds instead of 30+ seconds.