# Loop an "If Else" statement for comparing daily covid increases in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, dplyr

Below is a snippet of data I am working with.

Flu
Day Positive Total
1 2 2
2 1 3
3 2 5
4 0 5
5 3 8
6 4 12
7 7 19
8 8 27
9 9 36
10 15 41

I am trying to write a loop with an if/else statement to determine if the one value in the Positive column is either "Higher" or "Lower" than the previous value. Doing so would then create a new column named "Trend" and would populate the row accordingly with "Higher" or Lower"

```
 {
if(Flu$Positive[i+1]>Covid$Positive[i]))
   Trend = "Higher"
else
   Trend = "Lower"
   }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic lag in R vector/dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558988/basic-lag-in-r-vector-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `diff` to create the logical vector

```
with(Covid, c("Lower", "Higher")[c(FALSE, diff(Positive) > 0) + 1])
#[1] "Lower"  "Lower"  "Higher" "Lower"  "Higher" "Higher" "Higher" "Higher" "Higher" "Higher"
```

---

If we need a loop, initiate an output vector with 'Lower' values, then loop over the sequence of rows, check `if` the current value of 'Positive' is greater than the previous row values, assign the vector for that row to 'Higher'

```
v1 <- rep("Lower", nrow(Covid))
for(i in 2:nrow(Covid)) if(Covid$Positive[i] > Covid$Positive[i-1]) v1[i] <- "Higher"
v1
# [1] "Lower"  "Lower"  "Higher" "Lower"  "Higher" "Higher" "Higher" "Higher" "Higher" "Higher"
```

#### data

```
Covid <- structure(list(Day = 1:10, Positive = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 7L, 14L), Total = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 14L, 
21L, 35L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: this seems more smooth then a loop would be. It did work for my dataset, however, for my own sake of trying to understand how to write a loop, how would I write this as loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lag function to do it like so:

```
Covid$New <- ifelse(Covid$Positive > lag(Covid$Positive, 1L),"Higher","Lower")
```

**Please note that with higher and lower only you are not addressing "Same", which is one of the conditions.

```
Covid <- structure(list(Day = 1:10, Positive = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 7L, 14L), Total = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 14L, 
21L, 35L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

Covid$NewCol <- ifelse(Covid$Positive > lag(Covid$Positive, 1L),"Higher","Lower")

print(Covid)
   Day Positive Total    New
1    1        1     1   <NA>
2    2        0     1  Lower
3    3        1     2 Higher
4    4        0     2  Lower
5    5        1     3 Higher
6    6        2     5 Higher
7    7        4     9 Higher
8    8        5    14 Higher
9    9        7    21 Higher
10  10       14    35 Higher
```