# Creating leading variables in R

Tags: r

I want to create a leading variable in R where given old variable `x`, new variable `y` is such that `y[t] = x[t+1]`
e.g. as in [Lagging Variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311920/lagging-variables-in-r)

`embed()` the solution in above doesn't let you use dimension < 1. Is there an alternative built-in function that will help here?

Answer (score 6):

If `x` is your original variable, then `y <- c(x[-1], NA)` is a leading version.